# Error while printing simple value

Tags: php, twig

I received this error:

> Type: Twig_Error_Syntax Message: Arguments must be separated by a
>   comma. Unexpected token "name" of value "h_open" ("punctuation"
>   expected with value ",").

I can't show the field `ticker.24h_open`

```
       {% if ticker %}
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-3">
                        {{ ticker.amountAssetName }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-3">
                        {{ ticker.amountAssetID }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-3">
                        {{ ticker.amountAssetDecimals }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-3">
                        {{ dump( ticker.24h_open) }}
                    </div>
                </div>          
        {% endif %}
```

is 24 a reserved keyword in twig?

Comment: methods / variables can't start with a number. Change your property name or use `{{ ticker['24h_open'] }}`

Comment: Using ticker['24_open'] gives me null. ticket is an object, not an array. I can succesfully display and access ticker.amountAssetDecimals and the other attributes. It seems that this API is incompatible with twig.

Comment: If it's an object u'd need to use `attribute` as Dormilich suggested

Comment: I got around it by using json_encode(curloutput, true) and getting an array instead of an object, then i made the computation in PHP and added a supported variable to the array:

`$ticker['minimumFee'] = round( 0.001 / $ticker['24h_close'] * pow( 10,$ticker['amountAssetDecimals']),0);`

**View**

`<td>
{{ ticker.minimumFee  }}
</td>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is 24 a reserved keyword in twig?

no, but an invalid variable name. Twig uses the `attribute()` function to access via array key.

Related Example:

```
{{ attribute(ticker, '24h_close') }}
```

Comment: so why i can display ticker.amountAssetDecimals and not ticket.24h_open? (i am using twig 1.x) I tried with

`{{ dump( attribute(ticker, 24h_open)) }}` 

but i receive this error: Message: Arguments must be separated by a comma. Unexpected token "name" of value "h_open" ("punctuation" expected with value ",").

Comment: It's `{{ dump( attribute(ticker, '24h_open')) }}`, if you don't enquote is, you are just making the same mistake again